# I would like to do as with PHP but in ktor

Tags: ktor

I would like to do as with PHP but in ktor. That is to say, to make forms with the processing directly in the HTML code, if there is an error displayed this or that, etc ...

equivalent of ejs in javascript with express

Comment: Since `ejs` is Embedded JavaScript templating I assume you want to know how to do templating in Ktor. Here https://ktor.io/docs/working-with-views.html you can find different methods of HTML and CSS generation.

Comment: I already tried FreeMarker and I didn't like it at all, what I would like is really like php, I put a tag you I do everything in it, stuff like freemarker is not really possible ...